# random images in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make my images to shuffle using the following code using jQuery, but I got stuck.

```
const $images = [
    { name: "dinosaurs", image: "../Images/dinosaurs.jpg"},
    { name: "friends", image: "../Images/Friends.jpg" },
    { name: "badguys", image: "../Images/bad_pack.jpg"}
];


const $random = () => {
    for(let character of $images) {
        console.log(character);
        const $square = $("#draw-square");
        $square.css("background", $images[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)].image
    
        )}
}
```

Any suggestions, thanks

Comment: To set a background image you would need `$square.css('background', 'url("' + $images[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)].image + '")';`. Have a nice day.

Comment: hey Rolando, it did work..... I forgot to put the ` at the end.... You are the greatest. thanks